# increase the counter value and update the data in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In localStorage, the "counters" key contains a JSON object whose fields are the names of counters and whose values are the numeric value of the counter. Write the incrementCounter function, which is passed the counterName - the name of the counter as the first parameter.

The task of the function is to increase the counter Name counter value by 1 and update the data in localStorage. LocalStorage may contain invalid JSON, which reading may lead to an error. in this case, the function should write new data, where the specified counter will have the value 1. At the end, the function should return the counter value after increment.

Example of use:

```
// in localStorage 1 counter: bannerClick = 5
     incrementCounter('bannerClick'); // 6
     incrementCounter('bannerClose'); // 1
// in localStorage 2 counter: bannerClick = 6, bannerClose = 1
```

Help with the implementation of the task. I only understand how to parse it

```
   function incrementCounter(counterName){
   const newObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counters'))
```

but I don't know what to do next. explain how to do this step by step

Answer (score 1):

```js
function incrementCounter(counterName){
    // Initialize a variable to store the counters object
    let counters;

    // Safely try to parse the data in localstorage
    try {
        counters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("counters"));
    } catch (er) {
        // In case localstorage doesn't have a valid JSON make a new object
        counters = {};
    }

    if(typeof counters[counterName] !== 'number'){
        // if the counter is not initialized in the object, initialize it
        counters[counterName] = 0;
    }

    // Now we can safely increment its value in the counters object
    counters[counterName]++;

    // Now that the value is updated, store it back in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("counters", JSON.stringify(counters));

    // Return the updated value of the counter in question
    return counters[counterName];
}
```

If you're using this in production, I'd advise against this kind of approach because accessing localStorage happens synchronously which might slow down your app if you're doing it a lot.